# CreateWindow() in Visual C++ always return null

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2012

Here is my code, in the WinMain entry point i registered a class and tried to create a window, but the CreateWindow() function always return NULL. However the RegisterClass() function did succeed. What have i done wrong?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


LRESULT CALLBACK event(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
{


    return 0;
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow
    )
{
    WNDCLASS wndClass;
    wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = event;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = L"ME";
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    int err = RegisterClass(&wndClass);
    if (err < 0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Can not register window class!", L"Error", 0);
        return -1;
    }
    HWND hwnd;
    hwnd = CreateWindow(L"ME",
    L"Test",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
    100,
    100, 
    300, 
    300, 
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance, 
    NULL);
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Can not create window!", L"Error", 0);
        return -1;
    }
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_NORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use your wndClass in your CreateWindow function?

Comment: At least do some error checking before asking. What does `GetLastError` say? The documentation mentions it specifically right near where it says that a null return value is failure. You're also incorrectly checking `RegisterClass` for failure: *If the function fails, the return value is zero.*

Comment: @Grantly, You can't use the window class object directly. You have to use either the name of a registered class or the atom you get from registering it.

Comment: GetLastError() function returns 0.

Comment: RegisterClass() returns 50516.

Comment: This program is practically identical to [Error 1813 when calling CreateWindow() func WinApi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891741/error-1813-when-calling-createwindow-func-winapi), and the reason is the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK event(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
{
    return 0;
}
```

That's a fundamentally broken window procedure.  Calling DefWindowProc() for messages that you don't handle yourself is **not** optional.

Right now it will not create the window because because you return FALSE for the WM_NCCREATE message.  It is supposed to return TRUE to allow the window to be created.  You won't get an error code from GetLastError() either, as far as the OS is concerned you intentionally refused to allow the window to get created.  Fix:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK event(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```