# CreateWindow never triggers WM_CREATE

Tags: windows-8, wndproc

I have the following bit of code;

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    printf("%d\n", message);

    return 0;
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){

    WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
    wc.lpszClassName = "oglversionchecksample";
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
        return 1;

    CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, "openglversioncheck", WS_OVERLAPPED, 0, 0, 640, 480, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Calling `CreateWindow()` triggers message numbers 36 `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`, 129 `WM_NCCREATE`, and then 130 `WM_NCDESTROY`, but message number 1 `WM_CREATE` is never triggered like it's supposed to be.

What am I doing wrong that's causing `WM_CREATE` to not be triggered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreateWindow() in Visual C++ always return null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493124/createwindow-in-visual-c-always-return-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't trigger any message, because message loop is not called yet.

You have to put this after `CreateWindow`

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Also, `WndProc` should not simply return zero. It should return the following:

```
return DefWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
```

Visual Studio or other IDE's can create C++ -> Win32 project basic project, it sets up all the code.

Comment: You got it. The problem was the `return 0;` was keeping the window from being created. The `GetMessage()` part isn't required to trigger `WM_CREATE`.

Answer (score 2):

The created window has no time to receive the messages, it is closed immediately. You should call GetMessage in loop to keep the window alive.

```
// Step 3: The Message Loop
while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}
return Msg.wParam;
```

See this example: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html